# horizontal listview for images

Tags: android, horizontallist

I need to show images in horizontally.I try to use Horizontal Scroll viewer.But the when number of images are high it gives me OutofMemory error as it doesn't hadle the loading images automatically it trys to load all images to memory.So is there a Horizontal list view in Android ?

Comment: Better to used View Pager and recycled your Bitmap after used it...

Comment: how to recycle the Bitmap after using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add entry in Manifest.xml , application tag -> android:largeHeap="true"

```
eg:
    <application
            android:name="APP_NAME"
            ..
            android:largeHeap="true"
             ..> </application>
```